# how to clear NSTimer memory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I'm using `NSTimer` to display seconds on a label while recording.
I'm starting the timer when the record button is tapped and stopping it when the stop button is tapped.
When I tap the play button the timer is not restarting.

```
-(void)startTimer
{
 playTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(timerController)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}
- (NSString*)getTimeStr : (int) secondsElapsed
{
seconds = secondsElapsed % 60;
int minutes = secondsElapsed / 60;
int hours = secondsElapsed/3600;
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
}

- (void)timerController{
seconds++;
[[self timeLabel] setText:[self getTimeStr:(seconds)]];
}

- (IBAction)recordTapped:(id)sender {
[self startTimer];
}

- (IBAction)stopTapped:(id)sender {
 [playTimer invalidate];
  playTimer=nil;
 _timeLabel.text=@"00:00:00";
}

- (IBAction)playTapped:(id)sender {
[self startTimer];
}
```

Comment: to restart the timer, you should reset the `seconds` variable to 0 at the beginning of `startTimer` function

Comment: Thank you working perfectly.

Comment: just i noticed my timer only running for 1 minute.after again it is starting from     00:00:01. can you help me on this

Comment: There is another bug I overlooked. You reused the variable `seconds` in the `getTimeStr:` function, which makes the `seconds` variable always go less than or equal to 59. Replace `seconds` with `int sec`, and of course, change the variable in the last line of the function to `sec` as well

Comment: ok i failed in a small bug. now working good

Comment: summarized the comments as answer below. If you find it useful, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are two bugs around:

**Bug #1**

You should always reset the variable `seconds` to 0 before restarting the timer (probably reset it at the 1st line of `startTimer`)

**Bug #2**

The variable `seconds` is overwritten by the 1st line of `getTimeStr` function. You should replace `seconds` with `int sec` and for the `return` line, replace `seconds` with `sec`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)resetTimer {
    if(playTimer) {
        [playTimer invalidate];
        playTimer = nil;
    }
}
```

You should call `resetTimer` method every time before `startTimer` again.